# How do I replicate row in a group with size < 3 within a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas. I have the following dataframe:

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Data | Data |
| 1 | Data | Data |
| 2 | Data | Data |
| 3 | Data | Data |
| 3 | Data | Data |
| 3 | Data | Data |
| 3 | Data | Data |

I want to replicate every row 3 times for a group with a size < 3. The dataframe will look like this:

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Data | Data |
| 0 | Data | Data |
| 0 | Data | Data |
| 1 | Data | Data |
| 1 | Data | Data |
| 1 | Data | Data |
| 2 | Data | Data |
| 2 | Data | Data |
| 2 | Data | Data |
| 3 | Data | Data |
| 3 | Data | Data |
| 3 | Data | Data |
| 3 | Data | Data |

Does anyone have ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So if there are 2 values in some group after repeat get 2*3=6rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for count column, and if less like `3` set values to `3` else `1` for no repeat, then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and repeat rows by [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
s = df['ID'].value_counts().lt(3).map({True:3, False:1})

df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['ID'].map(s))]
print (df)
   ID     A     B
0   0  Data  Data
0   0  Data  Data
0   0  Data  Data
1   1  Data  Data
1   1  Data  Data
1   1  Data  Data
2   2  Data  Data
2   2  Data  Data
2   2  Data  Data
3   3  Data  Data
4   3  Data  Data
5   3  Data  Data
6   3  Data  Data
```

If there are some group with `2` values after repeat get:

```
print (df)
   ID     A     B
0   0  Data  Data
1   1  Data  Data
2   2  Data  Data
3   2  Data  Data
4   3  Data  Data
5   3  Data  Data
6   3  Data  Data

s = df['ID'].value_counts().lt(3).map({True:3, False:1})
print (s)
3    1
2    3
0    3
1    3
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

---

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['ID'].map(s))]
print (df)
   ID     A     B
0   0  Data  Data
0   0  Data  Data
0   0  Data  Data
1   1  Data  Data
1   1  Data  Data
1   1  Data  Data
2   2  Data  Data
2   2  Data  Data
2   2  Data  Data
3   2  Data  Data
3   2  Data  Data
3   2  Data  Data
4   3  Data  Data
5   3  Data  Data
6   3  Data  Data
```

But if need repeat if 1 values 3 times, if 2 values 2 times else no repeat (repeat 1) solution is change:

```
s = df['ID'].value_counts().map({1:3, 2:2}).fillna(1)
print (s)
3    1.0
2    2.0
0    3.0
1    3.0
Name: ID, dtype: float64

df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['ID'].map(s))]
print (df)
   ID     A     B
0   0  Data  Data
0   0  Data  Data
0   0  Data  Data
1   1  Data  Data
1   1  Data  Data
1   1  Data  Data
2   2  Data  Data
2   2  Data  Data
3   2  Data  Data
3   2  Data  Data
4   3  Data  Data
5   3  Data  Data
6   3  Data  Data
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with the [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html)ped counts to have a minimum of 3:

```
s = df.groupby('ID')['ID'].size().clip(lower=3)

out = df.loc[s.index.repeat(s).rename(None)]
```

output:

```
   ID     A     B
0   0  Data  Data
0   0  Data  Data
0   0  Data  Data
1   1  Data  Data
1   1  Data  Data
1   1  Data  Data
2   2  Data  Data
2   2  Data  Data
2   2  Data  Data
3   3  Data  Data
3   3  Data  Data
3   3  Data  Data
3   3  Data  Data
```

intermediates:

```
s
# ID
# 0    3
# 1    3
# 2    3
# 3    4
# Name: ID, dtype: int64

s.index.repeat(s).rename(None)
# Int64Index([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], dtype='int64')
```